# yaml-cpp error while converting Node to a std::string

Tags: c++, c++20, yaml-cpp

I want to convert a Node object from [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) to a `std::string`. I keep getting an error that says it cannot find the right overloaded operator `<<`.
Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    YAML::Node myNode;
    myNode["hello"] = "world";
    cout << myNode << endl; // That works but I want that not to stdout

    string myString = "";
    myNode >> myString; // Error at this line
    cout << myString << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
src/main.cpp:13:12: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('YAML::Node' and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>')
[somefile] note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'YAML::Node' to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
  operator>> (byte  __lhs, _Integer __shift) noexcept
  ^
[A bunch of these 10+]
```

Using `clang++ -std=c++20 -I./include -lyaml-cpp -o prog main.cpp`

Please help me find out!

Comment: Does this node type have an `operator>>` that takes a string?

Comment: Use `std::stringstream`? Or `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: `std::stringstream` worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually needed to create an `stringstream` and then convert it to an normal string:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    YAML::Node myNode;
    myNode["hello"] = "world";

    stringstream myStringStream;
    myStringStream << myNode;
    string result = myStringStream.str();

    cout << result << end;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello: world
```

Comment: You should use `std::ostringstream` instead.